# Detect the local minimum in a one dimensional array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a one-dimensional array of integers. The array may look like something shown below. The BOLD is a subset showing the object, and I would like to detect those.

> 4806 4706 4686 4732 4644 4660 4618 4684 4722 4878 4872 4860 4840 4832
>   4828 4822 4814 4806 4792 4778 4782 4774 4766 4758 4758 4754 4738 4736
>   4786 4780 4772 4766  4764 **1996 2006 2002 1994 1998 2002** 4752 4756
>   4740 4762 4756 4766 4762 4772 4764  4664 4518 4564 4520 4420 4540 4550
>   4500 4494 4498 4584 4540 4550 0 0 0 3342 3352  3338 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 4762 4754 4640

Or:

> 4806 4708 4680 4732 4650 4658 4630 4688 4726 4878 4866 4856 4844 4836
>   4830 4824 4810 4794 4798 4788 4778 4766 4770 4764 4756 4750 4742 4732
>   4780 4776 4772 4772  4770 4760 4754 4760 4758 4758 **3908 3768 3766**
>   4804 4754 4764 4764 4766 4766 4764  4676 4520 4562 4534 4422 4540 4542
>   4498 4496 4502 4578 4540 4538 0 0 0 0 0 3338  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4758
>   4752 4632

As the data indicates, I have a set of data that represent distance feed back from a sensors. I want to detect how far the object is from my sensors. The easiest way to tell is by looking at the data feedback profile and see that a uniform sub-set of data that may resemble the object is being picked up. Ideally, I am trying to detect the object which face directly in the center of my sensor's FOV. So, the near-center of the feedback data is where I am most interested.

**Note:** The sensors have noise.

I have some idea of how to approach this and I have already done it to test out. But, I believes there are better method to approach this problem and I am keen to learn new method.

So my ideas are as follow:

1: Pick a small subset of the center of the sensors and average them.

2: Find the lower bound and upper bound of the near-center subset data. Where, lower bound is where the objects first picked up and upper bound is where the object last detected.

```
static int[] rangeFromeCenter = new int[80];
private static void calculateAverage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   count++;

   /// average method
   int sum = 0;
   int average = 0;

   for (int i = 189; i < 191; i++)
   {
      sum += responseLMS[i];
   }

   average = sum / 2;
   Console.WriteLine("\nAverage method \t" + average);
   // end average method

   /// bound finder method
   Array.Copy(responseLMS, 150, rangeFromeCenter, 0, 80);
   int lowerbound = 0;
   int lowerboundPreveius = 0;
   int difference = 0;
   int lowerboundi = 0;
   int upperboundi = 0;

   // find lower bound
   for (int i = 0; i < rangeFromeCenter.Length/2; i++)
   {
      if (rangeFromeCenter[i] != 0 || rangeFromeCenter[i + 1] != 0)
      {
         difference = rangeFromeCenter[i + 1] - rangeFromeCenter[i];
         lowerbound = difference;
         if (lowerbound < lowerboundPreveius)
         {
            lowerboundPreveius = lowerbound;
            lowerboundi = i + 1;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         //Console.WriteLine(" Zero found Lowerbound");
      }
   }

   for (int i = lowerboundi; i < rangeFromeCenter.Length -1; i++)
   {
      if (rangeFromeCenter[i] != 0 || rangeFromeCenter[i + 1] != 0)
      {
         difference = rangeFromeCenter[i + 1] - rangeFromeCenter[i];
         if (difference > 10)
         {
            upperboundi = i;
            break;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         //Console.WriteLine(" Zero found upperbound");
      }
   }
}
```

Another method is: finding the big jumped up and the big jumped down like as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rangeFromeCenter.Length; i++)
{
    if (rangeFromeCenter[i] != 0 || rangeFromeCenter[i + 1] != 0)
    {
        difference = rangeFromeCenter[i] - rangeFromeCenter[i + 1];
        if (difference > 200)
        {
            lowerboundi = i +1;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(" Zero found upperbound");
    }
}

for (int i = lowerboundi; i < rangeFromeCenter.Length -1; i++)
{
    if (rangeFromeCenter[i] != 0 || rangeFromeCenter[i + 1] != 0)
    {
        difference = rangeFromeCenter[i + 1] - rangeFromeCenter[i];
        if (difference > 200)
        {
            upperboundi = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(" Zero found upperbound");
    }
}
```

If you have any comments on my existing approach please input. I would love to hear your feedback. Or, if you have any other approach to find the local minimum please advise.

Here is a link to a picture that I drew for better viewing of the problem and what I am trying to do:

[image: Local Minimum]

Comment: what about the 0s and 3338 at the end of the second set?

Comment: You don't have sufficient information here to give a useful answer.  What defines an "object" signal?  Why do the bolded numbers count, yet the series of zeroes in the first set do not?  etc..

Comment: the series of zero, or any zeros are noise or sensor error

Comment: have a look at Histogram-based Segmentation. You are trying to separate two random distributiond from another

Comment: As others have said - what makes an object? Looking at your datasets my guess would be the start of an object's readings are defined by having a larger difference between that reading and the previous reading (larger than X, where you tune your sensitivity on X) and the end of the object's readings are defined by similarly large difference. But really, *you* should tell us why those numbers you've put as bold are considered objects?

Comment: The problem is not well defined. It cannot be solved manually in an unambiguous way, so it cannot be solved automatically by the software, either. _You_ need to _define_ what constitutes an object in the first place, in a totally unambiguous way.

Comment: @Mashton You are absolutely right. And I did the exact same thing as one of my other approach. So basically I try to find a big jumped down and a big jumped up in the numbers.

Comment: Please look at the link (at the very bottom of the question) to the image which will shows more information of what i am trying to explain

Comment: "Big jump" is ambiguous. What is a big jump? What is a small jump?

Comment: Big jumped down is where I check if Array[i] - Array[i -1] > 100
Big jumped up is where I check if Array[i +1 ] - Array[i] > 100

However, 100 is too big for me to tolerate. But, the data sometime has noise bigger than 100 so which is really hard for me to identify.

Comment: This post finished a reopen review one vote short. I voted to reopen; however, this question might be too broad for Stack Overflow, which is for specific questions about coding that can have definite answers. Discussions of high-level design concepts and best practices are more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/82990/228805) for more information. I'm flagging it for migration.

Comment: so does anyone has any advise?

Comment: I would take a serious look into products such as Matlab that have functions that do exactly this (and well). There are some open source options (GNU Octave, Sage). Maybe look at something like: [OctaveSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342007/OctaveSharp-Running-GNU-Octave-with-Csharp). I have to admit that I have used none of these (for this), so your distance may vary.